# Does The Following Sentence Contain Grammar Mistake?

Tags: grammar

I feel as though the following sentence lacks commas and such, but I wouldn't know. I'm in the middle of working on an article.

> Thanks for asking, imaginary person I just created to get my point
>   across.

Comment: It's unusual in that relative clauses embedded into vocatives are quite rare in English. There is nothing grammatically or punctuationally wrong with it, though.

Comment: It's very unnatural English. Final vocatives are pronounced with artificially low intonation (_Thanks for asking, Bill_) to distinguish them from nouns with a use in the sentence. That's represented in print by the comma, but the intonation is extremely hard to sustain for 18 syllables, while simultaneously parsing a relative clause with complementizer deletion, a purpose clause with complementizer deletion and Equi-subject deletion, in an idiomatic verb phrase. That's kind of like juggling on a unicycle while singing the national anthem; it's asking a lot of your reader.

Comment: It's my website's blog, I'm comedic when writing. Thanks! I decided to rephrase the ending but I think this makes less sense. "Thanks for asking, imaginary person that I just created to answer my own question." He's not the one who answered it, but it sounds funny. I created him to help ME answer my own question. A bit comedic is what I'm trying to be.

Comment: Also, I have read about 1,000 blogs in my time and have seen most of them do what I do, just differently phrased. It's more of a writing style to be funny and serious with the topic at the same time

Comment: Your example sounds okay, in the context that it is something that Jimmy Fallon does on a comedic bit on his nightly show (currently "The Tonight Show"). He answers imaginary letters. :)

Answer (score 4):

The grammar in your sentence is not wrong and the sentence works at a comical level. The grammar in your headline, however, is atrocious.

Answer (score 2):

That sentence is correct. However there are a number of other ways that it could be written, if you'd prefer.

You could add the word "that":

```
Thanks for asking, imaginary person *that* I just created to get my point across.
```

Or you could hyphenate the temporary compound. This could make it easier for the reader to understand.

```
Thanks for asking, imaginary-person-I-just-created-to-get-my-point-across.
```

Comment: _That_ is not a restrictive clause. It's a conjunction. The relative clause is restrictive whether or not _that_ is overtly expressed.

Comment: You're right, sorry. Edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks! I decided to rephrase the ending but I think this makes less sense. "Thanks for asking, imaginary person that I just created to answer my own question." He's not the one who answered it, but it sounds funny. I created him to help ME answer my own question. A bit comedic is what I'm trying to be.

Comment: @user1925224 You might solve the problem with something like, "Thanks for asking, imaginary person that I just created to feed me easy questions."

Comment: Hey Moogle, the word "that" is not a conjunction--for the expression *"(that) I just created to get my point across"* is a relative clause and the word "that" is a relative word which sometimes is optional.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, although you could add *that* to make it more clear:

```
Thanks for asking, imaginary person *that* I just created to get my point across.
```

Comment: I see, thanks! Yeah, I asked something like "What's that? No, your Google account is safe. Thanks for asking..." etc. So I think you're probably right with what you think.